# Problems with database connection using windows service as ef client

Tags: entity-framework-5

I am new to `Entity Framework`, after a crash course and some playing around my employer decided to use ef 5, code first.

I have separated the dbcontext derivative along with the repositories and connection strings in a assembly on its own. The idea is to create an assembly which can be reusable across projects.

The connection string in the database assembly looks like this:

```
<add name="LmsDb" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=LmsDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\LmsDb.mdf;;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

While the connection string on assemblies using the database project (the clients) looks like this:

```
<add name="LmsDb" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=LmsDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have created a MVC project which works just fine with this and all my integration tests works well with this connection string.

The problem occurred when I had to create some kind of scheduler logic to go through the database at some configurable intervals and do some actions according to the data there. I decided to test this out by creating a simple Windows Service with a Timer that executes the ef 5 code for some queries.

The timer is set to execute a Select all query every minute, but when this happends my query returns no results although I know that there is data in the database.

When I look at the `DbContext.Connection.State`, its set to Closed.

What am I doing wrong ?

I tried opening the connection explicit by using `((ObjectContextAdapter)my context).ObjectContext.Connection.Open()` according to Julie Lerman.

This didn't seem to help any though.

Comment: Never mind, I found the problem. Because I was using LocalDB by default, this put some restrictions on my data. LocalDb is supposed to work as a sandbox for the developer and its not supposed to be accessed by other users than the owner by default. My windows service was running as LocalSystem, changing this to my user account made the whole thing work. But no exceptions were thrown ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got resolved. Please look at my comment.